# notifyDataSetChanged failed to update my ListView in fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

In my case ,I use a fragment as a tab inside a activity. I want to load information when the fragment is created. so I use a Runnable to run the `httprequest` and put those response back to the custom handler inside the fragment where I call `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Here comes the problem, the listView inside the fragment failed to update its view after I called the method `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

I tracked the stack and found out that after the call of `notifyDataSetChanged()`, the Adapter did call its method `getCount()` and `getCount()` did return a value over zero, but the Adapter did not call its method `getView()` after the call of `getCount()`.

```
public class ProductReviewFragment extends Fragment {


private View mBackgroundView = null;

private ProductHelper mProductHelper = null;

private PullToRefreshListView mListView = null;

private int pre = 20;

private long mark = 0;

private long productId = 0;

private List<ProductThread> listProductThread = new ArrayList<ListProductReviewResponse.ProductThread>();

private class MyHandler extends Handler{
    private ProductReviewFragment mActivity = null;

    public MyHandler(ProductReviewFragment activity){
        mActivity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);

        switch (msg.what) {
        case ProductHelper.GET_PRODUCT_REVIEW_SUCCESS:
            ListProductReviewResponse response = (ListProductReviewResponse)msg.obj;
            if (response != null) {
                if (response.getProductThreadList()!=null) {
                    mActivity.listProductThread.addAll(response.getProductThreadList());
                }
                mActivity.mark = response.getMark();
                mActivity.mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            mActivity.mListView.onRefreshComplete();
            if (mActivity.listProductThread.size()>=response.getTotalNumber()) {
                mActivity.mListView.setMode(Mode.DISABLED);
            }
            break;
        case ProductHelper.GET_PRODUCT_REVIEW_FAILED:
            mActivity.mListView.onRefreshComplete();
            if (msg.obj!=null) {
                NetWorkException exception = (NetWorkException)msg.obj;
                NetWorkException.handlerResultNetWorkNotAvailable(mActivity.getActivity(), exception);
            }
        default:

            break;
        }

    }
}

private MyHandler mHandler = new MyHandler(this);

private class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        int i = listProductThread.size();
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listProductThread.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView==null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            convertView = View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.product_review_cell, null);

            holder.rivHead = (RoundImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.product_comment_head);

            holder.tvName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.product_comment_user);

            holder.tvContent = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.product_comment_content);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();

        holder.rivHead.setImageInfo(ImageInfo.obtain(ImageCategories.CATEGORY_ROUND_HEAD, listProductThread.get(position).getUser().getAvatarURL()));

        holder.tvName.setText(listProductThread.get(position).getUser().getUserName());

        holder.tvContent.setText(listProductThread.get(position).getContent());

        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        RoundImageView rivHead = null;
        TextView tvName = null;
        TextView tvContent = null;
    }
}

private MyAdapter mAdapter = new MyAdapter();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    if (bundle!=null) {
        productId = bundle.getLong(ProductHelper.PRODUCT_ID);
    }

    mProductHelper = new ProductHelper(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    mProductHelper.getProductReview(productId, mark, pre, mHandler);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mBackgroundView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pulltorefresh_list_fragment, null);
    return mBackgroundView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    initUI();

}

public void initUI(){


    mListView = (PullToRefreshListView) mBackgroundView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_listview);

    mListView.setMode(Mode.PULL_FROM_END);

    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}

}
```

Comment: y mActivity.mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();? u can simplely use adpter.noti.... and i could not see mAdapter declaration

Comment: the declaration of mAdapter is above the method onCreate()

Answer (score 0):

you have put your oncreate code in onCreateView method or on ActivityCreated method..because your Xml UI binding is in onCreateview method and onCreate method Called before onCreateView so just move your code...

Comment: thx for answering. Though I bind the Xml UI in the onCreateView method ,it don't matter. Cuz the data is set in the adapter. The data is free from the Xml UI. I try moving those code below but it doesn't work